# program for nothing

Tags: java

```
public class evenVSodd 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a; 
        a = 4;

        if (a/2==0)
        {
            System.out.print("its an even number");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("its a odd number");
        }
    }
}
```

the result is :

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java evenVSodd

its a odd number
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: `a/2` is not a boolean type. You might want to add some comparison operator. It also doesn't check parity correctly. `System.print.out` should be `System.out.print`.

Comment: thank you but i still cannot solve a/2 
is there any other way to solve that error

Comment: You need something like `if (a/2 == 0)` not just `if (a/2)`. Also, you might want to look at the `%` (modulo) operator.

Comment: Think about what your code means. What if `a=4`? What does `if(2)` mean in Java? What about `a=5`? Why is it still basically `if(2)`? You need another operator to determine parity.

Comment: ok i tried that but at anyways the result is odd number !

Comment: Like I said before, you need the `%` operator, not `/`. You are performing integer division and using the quotient when what you want is the remainder of division by 2.

Comment: ok right but can i have your help in what should be the code

Comment: We are trying to help you in a way which you may learn something. If we just write code for you then you don't learn anything or get better.

Comment: Your result is always odd because a=5 in your code

Comment: i tried a=4 still odd

Comment: We have suggested many changes and we are not sure which ones you have made or not. Update your question to include the newest version of code you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class EvenAndOdd {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a;
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);    
            System.out.println("Enter the Number :");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            if(a%2==0) {
               System.out.print("its an even number");
            }
            else {
               System.out.print("its a odd number");
          }
       }
    }
```

Run it and you'll get the output.

**NOTE :** After running the code, read the comments above as what they have to say and try to follow. This will improve you only